# Using SignalR in Worker Service Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, background-service

I have been searching high and low on how to configure this properly and nothing seems to be working for me.

I have been mostly following the following article from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and adjusting for my own needs as I go.

Using .Net 5.0

For starters, what I am trying to do is create a **SignalR** connection between my **Web UI** and my **BackgroundService**. When creating the background service I used **File -> New Project -> Worker Service** template to create this service. I need to be able to both send data to clients and recieve data from clients within the BackgroundService.

**Program.cs**

Here I add SignalR. Which seems pretty straightforward.

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("myContext")));
                services.AddSignalR();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

**Interface:**

This is where my understanding starts to break down. I think this is an interface to send data to the client?

```
public interface IDesoutterController
{
    Task SendData(DateTime currentTime);
}
```

**Controller Hub:**

Here is my hub contained in the worker service project with a function to send data to all clients.

```
public class ControllerHub : Hub<IDesoutterController>
{
    public async Task SendDataToClients(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendData(dateTime);
    }
}
```

**Controller Hub Client:**

This is where I am the most confused. Why is my service using a hub, and a hub client in this case or is it all poor wording? Is this just the portion to receive data from my Web UI? Would my web UI project call the endpoint /hubs/controller??

```
public partial class ControllerHubClient : IDesoutterController, IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ControllerHubClient> _logger;
    private HubConnection _connection;

    public ControllerHubClient(ILogger<ControllerHubClient> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("/hubs/controller")
            .Build();

        _connection.On<DateTime>("onSend", SendData);
    }
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Loop is here to wait until the server is running
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                await _connection.StartAsync(cancellationToken);

                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _connection.StopAsync();
    }
    public Task SendData(DateTime currentTime)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{CurrentTime}", currentTime.ToShortTimeString());

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Worker Service:**

```
 public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IHubContext<ControllerHub, IDesoutterController> _controllerHub;
    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IHubContext<ControllerHub, IDesoutterController> controllerHub)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _controllerHub = controllerHub;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Other Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Really all I am trying to do is have a SignalR connection between by Web UI and Worker Service project to allow events to be sent (quickly). Each instance of my background service needs its own hub. Granted I am FAIRLY certain I am doing this all wrong. I do however get the following error whenever I start my worker service project.

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'GetStreamItemType' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated as I am completely new to background services and signalr.

**EDIT**

Here is a diagram of essentially the system I am trying to create. After reading some of the comments I wanted to clarify my worker service project does NOT have a startup.cs (a big part of why I was confused reading the Microsoft article). I think because I used the worker service template? In my case I "think" I was trying to put both the client and the hub in the same project. **After another suggestion in the comment I believe I would want the hub in my web UI project and make my background service the client connecting to the hub**?

So in the picture **switch around the UI to be the Hub and the Background Worker service(s) to be the client(s)**? When I say worker services, I mean I am creating a task for each device. So 1 "worker" thread per device.

[image]

Comment: So, the worker service is the signalr server and the website itself is the client? Or is the client of the website (the end user, using a browser) also the client of the worker service? I ask because you say "clients" plural but then talk like you want to link two servers (assuming single instances thereof, for now) using signalr.. unless you're planning on running multiple servers for the website I can't see clients plural? Can you sketch out the network diagram, actors, connections between them and connection type you're anticipating?

Comment: (Just noticed the note where said you'll have multiple background services, and I think you're implying one website, but all the rest of the post seems to say you're setting the service up to be the signalr server, which feels like the wrong way round to me; your one website then has to become a client of multiple servers but it's not a shared event architecture unless the website then relays the message to all connected signalr servers. Better to make the website the signalr server and the services the clients if you want one service to be able to write to all other instances of services)

Comment: Okay so i should probably be using the hub on the web app. Thinking about it now it does make a whole lot more sense to have the hub on the web side and make my background services the clients. Basically we have 4 physicial devices that will have 1 backgroundService each commumicating with it. I need to feed commands from my users in the web ui to the background service via signalR so the background service can send the appropriate byte data down to the physical device.

Comment: @CaiusJard I added the additional diagram and some more explanation.

Comment: Yes.. how you have your diagram now makes more sense to me. I would recommend you follow some tutorial about making a chat room with signalr; it's a good (well used) example of how signalr might facilitate a communication between client and server, and back. Try find one that is eg a console app clownt and web site based hub, as it will lend itself to swapping out the client console app for some kind of a service later